# Copy form fields from one form to another on checkbox tick

Tags: javascript, forms

As the title says I have a form for an address and a form for another address, both forms have the same fields.

When one form is filled a want the user to be able to check a box to copy the form data over to the other form as these will be the same values alot of the time.

I have all the text fields working, I'm just stuck with the dropdown menu for country.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function CopyAddress(f) {

        var SelCountry = document.getElementById("dCountry");
        var SelAccCountry = document.getElementById("dAccCountry");

        if (f.cCopyAddress.checked == true) {
            f.tAccAddress1.value = f.tAddress1.value;
            f.tAccAddress2.value = f.tAddress2.value;
            f.tAccTown.value = f.tTown.value;
            f.tAccCounty.value = f.tCounty.value;
            f.tAccPostcode.value = f.tPostcode.value;
            f.tAccTel.value = f.tTel.value;
            f.tAccFax.value = f.tFax.value;
            f.tAccEmail.value = f.tEmail.value;
            SelAccCountry.options[SelAccCountry.selectedIndex].value = SelCountry.options[SelCountry.selectedIndex].value;
      }
    }
</script>

<asp:CheckBox ID="cCopyAddress" runat="server" onclick="CopyAddress(this.form)" CssClass="autoWidth" />
```

If you would like me to past in the form code then just let me know but I didn't think it would be required as i don't think the error lies there.

Comment: Can you offer a sample demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar so we can see what you're working with? And what you're clicking to initiate the copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign `selectedIndex` property.

```
SelAccCountry.selectedIndex = SelCountry.selectedIndex;
```

Comment: Thanks antyrat thats done the trick...told you my javascript wasn't great!?! thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit() {
document.getElementById("two").value = document.getElementById("one").value;
}

</script>

<textarea id="one">text goes here</textarea>
<input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" onchange="doit()" />
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```